# Android sdk is said to be installed while installing android studio, but there is no such a Android file in /Library

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, sdk

I am installing Android studio on Mac and it says there is no sdk file found. Once I proceed, it says android sdk installed and it's grayed. but there is no Android sdk file.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just found that I am from Iran and google has been blocking us . That was the reason, if you ever faced this problem you just need to activate your VPN.